# VideoView not playing video (crash)

Tags: java, android

I made a `VideoView` for an app in Android Studio. The `VideoView` plays a video in a new view, pretty simple. It did work all the time, until I changed the source of the video. When I changed the source from `'handleiding'` to `'handleidingengels'`, the console gave the following error:

```
05-02 22:49:59.450  26710-26710/com.company.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ Unable to create media player
05-02 22:49:59.452  26710-26710/com.company.app D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
05-02 22:49:59.459  26710-26721/com.company.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
05-02 22:49:59.557  26710-26710/com.company.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
05-02 22:49:59.558  26710-26710/com.company.app D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-2147483648
05-02 22:49:59.586  26710-26710/com.company.app
D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-02 22:49:59.586  26710-26710/com.company.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ddd40)
05-02 22:49:59.589  26710-26710/com.company.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.app, PID: 26710
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:554)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
            at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:515)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:2264)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);

        fl.setLayoutParams(lp);


          final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;


            System.gc();
            Intent i = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

            VideoView vv = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(vv);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(lp);

        lp2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        vv.setLayoutParams(lp2);
            vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.handleidingengels));
            vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            vv.requestFocus();
            vv.start();

        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            }
        });
        }





    private void createNote() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Comment: Check the. URI you are passing for the video view, why drawable is used there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line

```
VideoView vv = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
```

You need to you the Activity context instead

```
VideoView vv = new VideoView(this);
```

Comment: Now it's giving the error that the movie can't be played

Comment: 'Unable to create media player'
'Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side'